# nested comprehension in python to generate date of years

Tags: python-3.x, python-datetime

I want to print all dates from 2013 to 2018 using comprehension in Python3.x

The below code is working fine for printing dates from 2013 to 2018 but only for the following months [1,3,5,7,8,10,12]:

```
print([datetime.date(i,j,k).strftime('%d %b %Y')  for i in range(2013,2019)
                                                    for j in range(1,13)
                                                      if j in {1,3,5,7,8,10,12} 
                                                         for k in range(1,32)])
```

But one more for loop inside elif is needed for rest of the months, and the following code is showing syntax error:

```
print([datetime.date(i,j,k).strftime('%d %b %Y')  for i in range(2013,2019)
                                                    for j in range(1,13)
                                                      if j in {1,3,5,7,8,10,12} 
                                                         for k in range(1,32)
                                                      elif j in {4,6,9,11}
                                                         for k in range(1,31)    
                                                      else
                                                         for k in range(1,29)])
```

I would be glad if someone can add code for leap year also in the same comprehension, if possible.

Comment: You can't just stick ifs randomly into a comprehension...

Comment: But the previous code was working. Is there any way to apply the same logic to one comprehension statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *really* want a list comprehension, then here you go!

Let's use another approach.

```
datetime.date(2013, 1, 1).toordinal() == 734869
datetime.date(2019, 1, 1).toordinal() == 737060
```

Here the numbers on the right are the number of *days* passed from January 1, year 1. Now you can just count the days starting from 734869 and get the new dates:

```
dates = [
    datetime.date.fromordinal(ordinal)
    for ordinal in range(
        datetime.date(2013, 1, 1).toordinal(),
        datetime.date(2019, 1, 1).toordinal()
    )
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome reply. It is working perfectly. You saved my day  **:)**

Comment: You're welcome! BTW, the version with `toordinal` is more readable than the one with timestamps, so you should probably use it instead.

Comment: This [toordinal approach] is better because of readability only or there is some difference in complexity also?

Comment: TBH, the timestamp one was actually throwing in a duplicate date for some reason... I think one can figure out why, but I just used another approach. So, the timestamp approach is actually a bit buggy :P